# Change the foreseeable name of a manytomanyfield in django

Tags: django

My aim is to change the foreseeable names of my fields in the admin site. For example I got the following class:

```
class todoList(models.Model):
        trainee = models.ForeignKey(trainee)
        tasks = models.TextField('Aufgaben')
        levyDate = models.DateField('Abgabedatum', null=True)
        priority = models.IntegerField(u'Priorität')
```

I can change the name of every field except the ForeignKey... For example I can name the "tasks" to "Aufgaben" but I can't do the same with trainee. Does anybody have a solution for this ?

Comment: I'm confused, why can't you declare a "verbose_name='Trainee'" in your ForeignKey field ?

Comment: okay that was pretty much all it took to solve my problem... I don't know why I did not try that myself but you can take that as the answer and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, ForeignKey fields need a verbose_name as key argument :

```
trainee = models.ForeignKey(Trainee, verbose_name='Trainee')
```

:)